# how to store retrieval values form database in variables?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

the number of rows in table course_details may be any. I retrieve these values and store in array a[]. Now the array contains values of one column(say course_names). Now i to store these values in database once again. my code:

```
$query1 = "select *from course_details WHERE branch='$branch' AND sem='$sem'";
            $run1 = mysql_query($query1) or die($query1."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 
            $a = array(10);   
            $i = 0;
            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($run1)){        
                $a[] = $row1['course_names'];
                $i++;
            }
            $cc1 = $a[1];
            $cc2 = $a[2];
            $cc3 = $a[3]; //upto here is ok since i have 3 rows in table
            $cc4 = $a[4];
            $cc5 = $a[5];
            $cc6 = $a[6];
            $cc7 = $a[7];
            $cc8 = $a[8];
            $cc9 = $a[9];
            $cc10 = $a[10];
```

I don't know how many rows may contain in the table. here i have to consider 10 values that may be in the table. So i am storing each field of column course_names in variables $cc1, $cc2 etc. But the error is because in table the number of row is only 3. So $cc4, $cc5, .. are all undefined. That is I want to store any number of values in a variables such that I can easily store once again in different table. Please help

Comment: `if(isset($row[4])){$cc4 = $row[4]}` it will never create $cc4, if $row[4] is not present

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html

Comment: Why do you think `$cc1` is better than `$a[1]`? This seems pointless.

Comment: @Jeffman..yes you are right

Comment: You don't need to specify the size of array you want to create. `$a = array();` is enough. Also, why don't you just use the array again instead of assigning them to variables? They're usable just like any other plain variables.

Comment: @Royal Bg...If I want to check several rows then what to do?

Comment: @Sutandiono...If I want to check several rows then what to do?